# Why styling is not applying to my elements?

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng

I have an angular app in which i have my nested dropdown menu. And in one of the list item i have `primeng` `Tabview` in that list item like this

```
<li *ngIf="user.role !== 'super'" class="nav-item flex-center-center flex-column min-width-40 no-border custom-bell-padding notifications-dropdown">
<a class="nav-link" id="notificationsDropDown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
    <i class="fal fa-bell font-26"></i>
</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="notificationsDropDown" (click)="onClick($event)">
    <span class="dropdown-menu-arrow"></span>
    <div class="ui-g header-dropdown-list">
        <div class="ui-g-12 list-item-border-bottom">
            <div class="ui-g-6">
                <p class="font-11 pb-0">Your Notifications</p>
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-6 font-11 text-right">
                <app-checkbox [disabled]="disabled" label="Technician updates" [isChecked]="true"></app-checkbox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-g-12">
            <p-tabView class="tab-panel-underline">
                <p-tabPanel header="All">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                    </ng-template>
                </p-tabPanel>
                <p-tabPanel header="Critical">
                    <ng-template pTemplate="content">
                    </ng-template>
                </p-tabPanel>
            </p-tabView>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now i am applying custom styling in `component.scss` like this

```
.notifications-dropdown{
  .dropdown-menu {
   left: 843px !important;
   margin: -0.875rem 0 0;
   font-size: 0.875rem;
   color: #7A8281;
   text-align: left;
   list-style: none;
   border: 0 solid #c8ced3;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
   z-index: 99999;
   top: 74px;
   border-radius: 0px;
   width: 20rem;
   /* min-width: 18.2rem; */
   /* right: 0px; */

         .header-dropdown-list{
    // height: 150px;
    .list-item-border-bottom{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e6e6;
    }
    p-tabview.tab-panel-underline {
        .ui-tabview{
          padding: 20px !important;
          .ui-tabview-nav li{
            width: 50% !important;
            padding: 0px !important;
          }
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

But my styling is not applying on `primeng tabview`. I have this `tabview` inside of my main list item i.e `li` and applying some padding and width of `li` of `primeng` `tabview` but it's not applying my custom styles.

Comment: Create an example on stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue. The problem was causing due to `ViewEncapsulation`. My problem solved when i put `ViewEncapsulation.None` inside my component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-deep and & opertor in scss which refrence to parent class.

```
::ng-deep .notifications-dropdown{
  .dropdown-menu {
   left: 843px !important;
   margin: -0.875rem 0 0;
   font-size: 0.875rem;
   color: #7A8281;
   text-align: left;
   list-style: none;
   border: 0 solid #c8ced3;
   box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
   z-index: 99999;
   top: 74px;
   border-radius: 0px;
   width: 20rem;
   /* min-width: 18.2rem; */
   /* right: 0px; */

         .header-dropdown-list{
    // height: 150px;
   & .list-item-border-bottom{
      border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e6e6;
    }
   & p-tabview.tab-panel-underline {
       & .ui-tabview{
          padding: 20px !important;
         & .ui-tabview-nav li{
            width: 50% !important;
            padding: 0px !important;
          }
        }
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Can you please generate the demo on stackblitz. I am not getting idea why it would not work.

Comment: i am not able to create stackblitz because for that i have to integrate whole `primeng` library in stackblitz and write my all necessary css styles in it. Can you see the problem on screen share?

Comment: Can we talk in chatroom ?